# Set variable colors on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm tryng to make a facet_wrap histogram with 2 different colors for y axis variables, my dataframe is composed of 3 variables and 6 obs:

```
dataset

# A tibble: 6 x 3
 Compound q_value DE_genes
  <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>
1 AFB1        0.05     5931
2 AFB1        0.1      7439
3 AFB1        0.4     13205
4 EE2         0.05     6055
5 EE2         0.1      7602
6 EE2         0.4     13294
```

Using the code I write I am able to make the graph but only with default ggplot colors instead of 2 manually selected colors:

```
ggplot(data = nDE_genes2) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = DE_genes, y = Compound, fill = Compound), width = 0.3)+
  facet_wrap(~q_vaue)+
  theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(colour = "white", size = 0.5, linetype = "dotted"))+
  scale_x_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(1000, 15000, 1000))+
  labs(title = "Number of DE gene",
   y = "compound")
```

[image: Graph]

Using scale_color_manual() function the result that I get is a graph with grey bar both setting values corresponding to the variable name both setting 6 repeated colors.

```
 ggplot(data = nDE_genes2) +
   geom_col(mapping = aes(x = DE_genes, y = Compound), width = 0.3)+
   facet_wrap(~q_vaue)+
   theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(colour = "white", size = 0.5, linetype = "dotted"))+
   scale_x_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(1000, 15000, 1000))+
   scale_color_manual(values = c("AFB1" = "#A8BAFD", "EE2" = "#FFF6B0"))+
   labs(title = "Number of DE gene",
   y = "compound")



ggplot(data = nDE_genes2) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = DE_genes, y = Compound), width = 0.3)+
  facet_wrap(~q_vaue)+
  theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(colour = "white", size = 0.5, linetype = "dotted"))+
  scale_x_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(1000, 15000, 1000))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#A8BAFD","#A8BAFD", "#A8BAFD", "#FFF6B0", "#FFF6B0", "#FFF6B0"))+
  labs(title = "Number of DE gene",
   y = "compound")
```

Can someone help me setting #A8BAFD and #FFF6B0 as column colors?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `scale_fill_manual`. In `ggplot2` graphics, `color` is the border, the interior is `fill`.

Comment: Just add `scale_fill_manual(values = c("AFB1" = "#A8BAFD", "EE2" = "#FFF6B0"))` to the first plot instructions.